# JSON response giving Http 500 internal server error

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am getting Internal Error when trying to make an ajax POST Call which returns JSON.
The ajax call is made from JS page:

```
$.post(
    'FilterAsJson',
    $(formWithReportData).serialize(),
    function(data){funtion_body}
);
```

This is my Spring MVC calling method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Reporting/FilterAsJson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody PagedQueryResult<GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult> filterAsJson(@ModelAttribute GetEntitleReportQuery query, HttpSession session)    
{
    getEntitlementOverviewFromSession(session).updateFromQuery(query, session);
    return queryDispatcher.dispatch(query);
}
```

The issue comes where I am setting only few fields in this class `GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult`(17 out of 30). This is a bean class with simple setter getters. If I set all the 30 fields it works fine.
Can you suggest how the JSON response is set so I can rectify this issue.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error
A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.
Most probably query error if accessing DB.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error means that your server encountered an error while processing the request.  Since you are using AJAX, you do not see the full message from the server.

2 Options:

A - Check the server logs

B - See below:

Best way I know of to check this with an asynchronous call is to press F12 to bring up your developer tools in your web browser.

Then, you click the "Network" tab on the browser tool and you can see all of the requests that your application makes.

Make your request that is giving you a 500 error, then find it in the list of network requests.  You should see the 500 error and be able to see the actual output (server response) that will give you an actual message.

Comment: I can find no errors in the console , the browser just returns "The message:Internal Server Error" . Does it have anything to do with fields that are not set after the query is getting executed? So the json parsing is failing? There is no issue with the query it runs fine.

Comment: Re-read my post.  You do not need to look at the console.  You need to look at the *network* tab on the debugger, and the response for the request that is giving you the error.  The console is for javascript errors, your error is from the request on the server.

Comment: The response is giving me 500 error only in the network tab in debugger. I also checked the server logs but no logs are present for this scenario. In the above filterAsJson method the dispatcher returns objects buy i think so it failing on converting this objects in reponse form. can you pleas help me why its failing.

Comment: See here http://getfirebug.com/network , you should be able to see the xmlhttp request that is made and the response from the server.

Comment: Yes , i don't get anything. It doesn't return back to the calling $post method, i.e. the callback method funtion(data){} is not reached. The response itself fails.

Comment: See my edit above, you need to use http://getfirebug.com/network to view the request and response in the browser.  If you do not do this and do not get a log message from the server, I cannot help you.

Comment: I have been using firebug only to track the response and like i said the response fails. xmlhttp resonse is nothing but 500 error :

Comment: </b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description
</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
</p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47</h3></body></html>

Comment: Modify your log4j.xml configuration to enable debugging for Spring web, and see what that tells you in the tomcat server logs.

Answer (score -1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Reporting/FilterAsJson", headers = "Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody PagedQueryResult<GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult> filterAsJson(@ModelAttribute GetEntitleReportQuery query, HttpSession session) {
    getEntitlementOverviewFromSession(session).updateFromQuery(query, session);
    return queryDispatcher.dispatch(query);
}
```

**UPDATED**
Oh, i see. I didn't understand question properly.

1. Show us please class GetEntitleReportQuery which propagate @ModelAttribute.
2. Also check what does method serialize when you filled not all fields. Does it exist?

**UPDATED**
An idea.
When u filled up not all fields of class, he try to find class with such fields and can't find. So, try to named your class in Controller and add binding result param: `filterAsJson(@ModelAttribute("query") GetEntitleReportQuery query, HttpSession session, BindingResult result)` also send from JSP with name "query".

Comment: Downvoted because this will not work, has no useful explanation and does not contribute anything.

Comment: The GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult class has a number of fields for eg. 30. there are two scenarios here , in first case the on dispatching to handler class, query is executed which returns all 30 elements and it is set into GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult bean object class one by one. In this case no Internal error is encountered. In second scenario the query fetched 17 rows and remaining 13 are null. So it only  sets 17 rows having value,to  the bean  while it skips the other 13 since  those contain "null". In this case we have a failure scenario.

Comment: @dikkini I have made changes to the filterAsJson method in the controller class as mentioned by you. and do you mean to say while making ajax call modify the $post call like this: $.post('FilterAsJson',      $(query).serialize(),function(data){}) .

Comment: @dikkini It did not work that way also. i am not able to figure out why few fields that are not set is causing so much problem. please suggest.